# Submit Button not working at all Simple_Forms Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I've been trying to find out why the form for a simple Posts_Controller isn't working properly. I'll post the code in question below.

**Posts_Controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to posts_path unless @post.user == current_user
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  #Only user can destroy his or her post
  def correct_user
    @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @post.nil?
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :email, :image, :video)
  end
end
```

**Posts_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}, :method => :post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'users/shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label>GoPost</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <p>Add a photo</p>
      <%= f.input :image, required: false, label: false %>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <p>Add a video</p>
      <%= f.input :video, required: false, label: false %>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :content, required: true, autofocus: true, class:'form-control', label: false %>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Post', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

The new form renders without an issue, but I cannot insert the data when I click on the submit button. I don't have any custom JS in the view, btw.

Answer (score 0):

The button with name `:submit` won't help, you'll need a submit input.

```
<%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Comment: The button is not firing when I click on it. It doesn't even show a change in the Server log. I only see this.  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered users/shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (50.0ms)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (55.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 492ms (Views: 436.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)